# How to align badges with list items in CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I place badges (images) in the margin left of an  list?

Here is an examle in HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
        Some text
    </li> 
    
    <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
        Some other text
    </li> 
</ul>
```

and CSS

```
body {
        margin-left: 200px;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    left: -80px;
}
```

Same example in live demo https://www.codeply.com/p/R2rUeDHoVC

Here is [what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nxJH.png)

Here is [what I have so fa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIwyT.png) (images create unwanted gaps in the text and hide the list bullets).

If there are multiple markers per item the group if images should grow to the left (all images should be right aligned).

I have tried various settings for display, position, flex etc. but somehow cannot figure out the right combination.

Comment: look into the css ::before selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution depends on the limited number of icons (images) but it can be improved.

**EDIT:** I edited the answer to keep the bullets.

```css
body {
        margin-left: 200px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
}

li .icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -65px;
}

li .icon:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -110px;
}

li .icon:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -160px;
}

li .icon:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -210px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
        Some text
    </li> 
    
    <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
        Some other text
    </li> 
    
    <li>
        <img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
        And even more text
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the list bullets, since there might be items that are not decorated. It seems that a modification of Ozgur's answer solves the problem. Maybe there is more elegant solution with the ::before selector suggested by DCR.

Comment: @DavidL I edited my answer to keep the bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on Ozgur's answer, but keeping the list bullets. Same code example available at https://www.codeply.com/p/r036MF41Fp

```css
body {
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: #fff;
}
    
li {
    position: relative;
}
    
li .icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -60px;
}
    
li .icon:nth-child(2) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -105px;
}

li .icon:nth-child(3) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -150px;
}

li .icon:nth-child(4) {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    left: -195px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
Some text. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lectus id quam iaculis condimentum. Aenean venenatis nec felis at dictum. Nullam vitae rhoncus est.
</li> 

<li>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
Some text 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lectus id quam iaculis condimentum. Aenean venenatis nec felis at dictum. Nullam vitae rhoncus est.
</li> 

<li>
Some text 3. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lectus id quam iaculis condimentum. Aenean venenatis nec felis at dictum. Nullam vitae rhoncus est.
</li>

<li>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/f60"/>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/ff0"/>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/660"/>
<img class="icon" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x30.png/6f0"/>

Some text 4. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ac lectus id quam iaculis condimentum. Aenean venenatis nec felis at dictum. Nullam vitae rhoncus est.
</li>           

</ul>
```